# UISearchController searchbar hides the first cell in tableview

Tags: uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I have a tableview with a search bar. The search bar is provided by a UISearchController. When I add the search bar to the header view of the table, the first row of the table gets covered by the search bar.

How do I prevent the search bar from hiding the first row?

I have this snippet in viewDidLoad:

```
self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self     
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: if you activate and then cancel the search bar, does it work correctly after?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you have to explicitly set the scope button titles array if you don't have scope button titles.

```
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray array];
```

Comment: As an additional comment, you must set this array _before_ you set it as a header or any calculations (such as sizeToFit) are taken into account.

Comment: This was necessary for iOS 8, I did not spot the layout problem in iOS 9. However this solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found this issue to be a layout constraints issue. Resolved by dropping all of my constraints in the view  containing my searchcontroller and adding back in individually until I found the offending constraint. Using Xcode 7.1

Comment: What specifically was the constraint that you had issues with?