# UITableView tableHeaderView overlaps first cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uisearchcontroller

For some reason, the headerView of my UITableView is overlapping the first cell.

[image]

Here is the code that sets up the UISearchController:

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;

self.itemsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true;
```

If I do a search, then cancel the search, the tableview will display correctly.

I'm not sure how to even begin fixing this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here [UISearchController searchbar hides the first cell in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405321/uisearchcontroller-searchbar-hides-the-first-cell-in-tableview)

Changing my code to this fixes the issue.

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray array];

self.itemsTableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
[self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true;
```